# Laravel 5.1 registration form with new field

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5, registration

I am creating referral system so I have the following routes

```
// Registration routes...
Route::get('auth/register/{id}', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

and my RegisterUser.php is changed to

```
public function getRegister($id)
{
    return view('auth.register')->withName($id);
}
```

and my blade looks like

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Company</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="company" value="{{ old('company') }}" readonly disabled>
    </div>
</div>
```

in AuthController I have:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'company' => $data['company'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

and the `value="{{ old('company') }}"` is causing the problem. When it is like that it works. But I want the value to be `value="{{$name}}"` given from `return view('auth.register')->withName($id);` So when I go to route `auth/register/something` in the input field I have got the 'something' so it is working but I have the error code `"Undefined index: company"`. When I remove the value at all it is working but I need this value. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: check if this solution suites you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem of your code is the disabled attribute in the input "company", why ? well  a disabled element isn't editable and isn't sent on submit. so Laravel doesn't receive it so you will be able to access via the helpers `old`.

Remove the `disabled` attribute and the magic happens.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="company" value="{{ old('company') }}" readonly >
```